# How to get syntax right for throwing custom exception?

Tags: c++, templates, exception

Can someone explain to me how to get this piece of code to compile? What's the syntax error here?

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
  public:
    class Overflow {};
};

template <typename T, typename QUEUE>
class Queue_Adapter : public Queue<T>
{
  public:
    void fun();
};

template<typename T, typename QUEUE>
void
Queue_Adapter<T, QUEUE>::fun()
{
  throw Queue<T>::Overflow();
}

int main()
{
  Queue_Adapter<int, int> tmp;
  tmp.fun();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the error message below:

```
test.cpp:19:19: error: 'Overflow' does not refer to a value
  throw Queue<T>::Overflow();
        ~~~~~~~~~~^
test.cpp:25:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Queue_Adapter<int,
      int>::fun' requested here
  tmp.fun();
      ^
test.cpp:5:11: note: declared here
    class Overflow {};
          ^
1 error generated.
```

(To get rid of the error message complaining about my question being mostly code...)

Comment: Make sure you use `typename` before `Queue<T>`.  You really shouldn't be using a nested class for exceptions, especially not one within a template.  That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: I found a C++ class online that had this class structure in the skeleton for part of a larger homework. Could you elaborate on why this is asking for trouble?

Comment: Because each instantiation of the template will have a different exception type(!) But yeah, the syntax error is purely due to a dependent type missing the explicit `typename` to help the parser understand that `Overflow` is a type in that context.

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is because the compiler thinks `<T>` consists of less-than and greater-than operators!  That is, it's parsing your statement as `throw (Queue) < (T) > (::Overflow());`

Comment: @Rufflewind that's not true - check out the duplicate link to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, if you change it to `throw typename Queue<T>::Overflow();`, it will work. And no, it's not parsing it as less-than and greater-than operators. Rather, since you didn't say that `Overflow` was the name of a type, it assumes that it's the name of a member function that you're trying to call (specifically pointed out in the error message, where it says: "in instantiation of member function..."

Comment: @DrewDormann, JerryCoffin: ah, I see, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thanks. Being new to C++ I'm often a bit confused about what the compiler means when it spits out an error. It's even worse if the error is from inside the STL... However, it now makes complete sense.

Comment: Yup--completely understandable (just be glad you weren't using C++ 15 to 20 years ago, when error messages were *really* awful).

Comment: I actually did some stuff with C++ in the late 90s (have forgot most of it since then) and remember how a very typical error message was "segmentation fault". Compared to that, it's definitely been improved. ;)